# insert/update data from one column to another with on conflict update, only those that have different values for specific fields?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-update, sql-insert

I have two columns `products/tmp_products` with following specification
*`(id bigint primary key ,price int not null,quantity int not null ,lastupdate timestamp)`*
I want sql to
                  Insert from tmp_products to products when id not in products.
                  Update only if (price or quantity) values are changed.

```
INSERT INTO products(id,price,quantity,lastupdate)
            SELECT  (id,price,quantity,lastupdate) FROM tmp_products
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET
    price=EXCLUDED.price,
    quantity=EXCLUDED.quantity,
    lastupdate=EXCLUDED.lastupdate
    where price!=EXCLUDED.price or quantity!=EXCLUDED.quantity;
```

I'm getting following error
`column reference "price" is ambiguous`
I want to know how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `where` clause. You need to qualify the columns so there are unambiguous:

```
INSERT INTO products(id,price,quantity,lastupdate)
SELECT id,price,quantity,lastupdate FROM tmp_products
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET
    price      = EXCLUDED.price,
    quantity   = EXCLUDED.quantity,
    lastupdate = EXCLUDED.lastupdate
WHERE products.price <> EXCLUDED.price OR products.quantity <> EXCLUDED.quantity;
```

Note that you also need to remove the parentheses around the `SELECT`, otherwise your query is not valid Postgres SQL, and would raise error `INSERT has more target columns than expressions`.